# tHiveInput in a loop/iterate?

Tags: talend

I currently have a file with a sql query on each row.
I'd like to read each row of this file with a tHDFSInput, and execute the query with a tHiveInput.
How can I do that ?
I have something like this :
[image]
But it just goes in the thiveinput only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the component `tFlowToIterate` between the `tHDFSInput` and the subjob with your `tHiveInput`.

In the below example, I generate a flow which contains a sequence of number then for each number, I do a request on my database(I confess it is not a tHiveInput but I guess it is the same logic).
[image]

Here is the configuration of the request I use in my `tDBRow_1`:

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried with a tFlowToIterate as propose and it works. Thx